# Installing Minecraft Mods on Game Panel in 1.17

Tags: minecraft

I want to run a 1.17 Origins Minecraft server, but I cannot for the life of me find out how to install mods. I'm running a 1.17 server through Hostinger and Debian 10 game panel. I got the server to work in vanilla but I can't find anywhere to actually upload mod files or datapacks.

Answer (score 0):

Run the fabric server from the Fabric made bat/sh files at least once, then the mods folder should appear in the server files. Place the mods there.

Then, to get datapacks, make sure the world has finished loading, then go to the world files, and in the world files there is a datapack folder there

Hope this helped